# Read property file into a dictionary in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a property file in key=value format
eg. File.properties
`context.root=ServerName
 http.port=1542
 db.user=abc
 db.password=xyx`

I want to load this property file in ansible as a dictionary. I can read one key value at a time like
`vars:
   db.user: "{{ lookup('ini', 'db.user type=properties file=File.properties') }}"`

But instead of getting each value separately i want all the key value pairs to be loaded as dictionary in ansible. Once loaded how would i use it to retrieve value for respective keys.

Comment: these variables can be declared inside inventory or var file, what is the use of dict ?

Answer (score 0):

The ini lookup is designed to return the *values*, not the entire contents; to have the properties as a `dict`, you'd want to parse the entire file. I can imagine two different approaches, depending on how complex your `.properties` file is:

1. first obtain the keys, then in a loop ask the existing `ini` lookup for their values
2. convert the .properties file into a `dict` the simplistic way; this won't work if you have line continuation characters or unicode escapes or other such things

For the first, something like:

```
 - debug: var=the_dict
   vars:
     the_dict: >-
      {%- set results = {} -%}
      {%- set keys = lookup("file", "File.properties").split("\n")
       | map("regex_replace", "^([^=]+)=.*", '\\1')
       | list -%}
      {%- for k in keys -%}
      {%-   set _ = results.update({k: lookup("ini", k+" type=properties file=File.properties")}) -%}
      {%- endfor -%}
      {{ results | to_json }}
```

For the second, you can take advantage of the fact that yaml is so liberal with its syntax:

```
 - debug:
     msg: >-
      {{ lookup("file", "File.properties").split("\n")
       | map("regex_replace", "^([^=]+)=(.*)", '"\1": "\2"')
       | join("\n")
       | from_yaml }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have directory where I'm keeping some files with scripts, orchestration files and ansible staff. There is **config/** , where global configuration files are kept and shared among different tools. Those configuration files are **key=value** pairs (property files) and I don't want to create yaml configuration file as some other tools cannot process it.

To make Ansible work with such configuration file I use next approach:

- Config file is being read and processed on **localhost**
- Using **sed in shell** it's **reformatted into yaml format** and stored as a text in variable via **register**
- It **read from text** by using filter **from_yaml** to some variable **X in set_fact**
- Dictionary with variables from property file is accessible on other nodes via **hostvars.localhost.X.PROPERTY**

sed pattern consists from 2 parts:

1. `/^ *$/d` - delete empty lines
2. `s@^\(.*\)=\(.*\)$@\1\ :\ "\2"@g`- grab everything from line's begging until "=" as capture group 1 and everything else into capture group 2. Reformat line into: **group_1 : "group_2"**

.

```
# Assuming that my property file config/tools_config has line:
# MOUNT_POINT=/mnt/shared

# Playbook
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: "Reformat configuration file"
    shell: sed '/^ *$/d;s@^\(.*\)=\(.*\)$@\1\ :\ "\2"@g' ../config/tools_config
    args:
      warn: false
    register: result

   - name: "Load configuration"
     set_fact:
       cfg: "{{ result.stdout | from_yaml }}"

- hosts: Y
  roles:
  - X

# roles/X/tasks/main.yaml
...
path: "{{ hostvars.localhost.cfg.MOUNT_POINT }}"
```