# How can I convert `key=value` file into Ansible facts?

Tags: ansible

I've got a file containing a few lines of simple shell-style (`key=value`, no whitespace or special characters) assignments. How would I go about converting this to a set of top-level facts using `ansible.builtin.set_fact`? `expandvars` looks like it might be relevant, but I can't find any examples or even any decent [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, given the configuration file

```
shell> cat conf.ini
key1=alpha=beta=charlie
key2=value2
key3= value3
```

The variable below

```yaml
config_vars: "{{ dict(lookup('file', 'conf.ini').split('\n')|
                      map('split', '=', 1)|
                      map('map', 'trim')) }}"
```

expands to

```yaml
config_vars:
  key1: alpha=beta=charlie
  key2: value2
  key3: value3
```

You can remove the last *map/trim* filter from the pipe if you're sure there are no spaces in the configuration file. But, to be on the safe side, I'd keep it.

---

**Config file at the remote host**

The solution in the previous section works at the controller only because the lookup plugins execute at the localhost. Fetch the files first if they are at the remote hosts. For example, given the configuration files

```
shell> ssh admin@test_11 cat /tmp/conf.ini
key1=alpha=beta=charlie
key2=value2
key3= value3
```

```
shell> ssh admin@test_12 cat /tmp/conf.ini
key1=value1
key2= value2
key3=alpha=beta=charlie
```

the playbook below

```yaml
- hosts: test_11,test_12
  vars:
    conf_ini_path: "conf_ini/{{ inventory_hostname }}/tmp/conf.ini"
    config_vars: "{{ dict(lookup('file', conf_ini_path).split('\n')|
                          map('split', '=', 1)|
                          map('map', 'trim')) }}"

  tasks:
    - fetch:
        dest: conf_ini
        src: /tmp/conf.ini
    - debug:
        var: config_vars
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [debug] ***********************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  config_vars:
    key1: alpha=beta=charlie
    key2: value2
    key3: value3
ok: [test_12] => 
  config_vars:
    key1: value1
    key2: value2
    key3: alpha=beta=charlie
```

---

**Alow no value**

For example, given the configuration file

```
shell> cat conf.ini
key1=alpha=beta=charlie
key2=value2
key3= value3
key4
```

The variable below

```yaml
config_vars: "{{ dict(lookup('file', 'conf.ini').split('\n')|
                      map('split', '=', 1)|
                      map('map', 'trim')|
                      map('json_query', '[]|[[0], [1]]')) }}"
```

expands to

```yaml
config_vars:
  key1: alpha=beta=charlie
  key2: value2
  key3: value3
  key4: null
```

Comment: FWIW, your `split` runs the risk of `alpha=beta=charlie` not doing the right thing, versus `regex_replace("^([^=]+)=(.*)$"...` [as shown in the existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55045920/read-property-file-into-a-dictionary-in-ansible/55081153)

Comment: Right. Set [maxsplit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) to 1. I updated the answer.

Comment: Bizarre that this isn't a builtin thing. Surely this is a common pattern people have to deal with all the time?

Comment: It's actually missing (not implemented) functionality both in the module [*ini_file*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ini_file_module.html#community-general-ini-file-module-tweak-settings-in-ini-files) and in the lookup plugin *ini* see ``shell> ansible-doc -t lookup ini``. Feel free to [contribute](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/index.html#plugins-in-community-general) it :)

Comment: I ended up using this without `trim` since I'm worried it could remove significant whitespace.

Comment: I added the code on how to read the configuration files at the remote hosts and on how to allow no value.