# Ansible: Get a value of first pair based on the value of a second pair's value

Tags: ansible

I have this file and I know the value of LOC for example /oracle/19.0.0.
Would like to get the value of HOME NAME=, the corresponding value would be OraDB19Home1.

Looked at lookup but unable to get it fully working. Appreciate any help.

```xml
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8' standalone = 'yes'?>
<!-- Copyright (c) 1999, 2022, Oracle. All rights reserved. -->
<!-- Do not modify the contents of this file by hand. -->
<INVENTORY>
   <VERSION_INFO>
      <SAVED_WITH>13.9.4.0.0</SAVED_WITH>
      <MINIMUM_VER>2.1.0.6.0</MINIMUM_VER>
   </VERSION_INFO>
   <HOME_LIST>
      <HOME NAME="OraHome1" LOC="/oracle/agent/agent13.4" TYPE="O" IDX="3"/>
      <HOME NAME="OraDB19Home1" LOC="/oracle/19.0.0" TYPE="O" IDX="2"/>
   </HOME_LIST>
</INVENTORY>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the XML

```xml
shell> cat inventory.xml 
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8' standalone = 'yes'?>
<!-- Copyright (c) 1999, 2022, Oracle. All rights reserved. -->
<!-- Do not modify the contents of this file by hand. -->
<INVENTORY>
  <VERSION_INFO>
    <SAVED_WITH>13.9.4.0.0</SAVED_WITH>
    <MINIMUM_VER>2.1.0.6.0</MINIMUM_VER>
  </VERSION_INFO>
  <HOME_LIST>
    <HOME NAME="OraHome1" LOC="/oracle/agent/agent13.4" TYPE="O" IDX="3"/>
    <HOME NAME="OraDB19Home1" LOC="/oracle/19.0.0" TYPE="O" IDX="2"/>
  </HOME_LIST>
</INVENTORY>
```

---

Read the file and convert XML to YAML

```yaml
  inv_xml: "{{ lookup('file', 'inventory.xml') }}"
  inv_yml: "{{ inv_xml|ansible.utils.from_xml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  inv_yml:
    INVENTORY:
      HOME_LIST:
        HOME:
        - '@IDX': '3'
          '@LOC': /oracle/agent/agent13.4
          '@NAME': OraHome1
          '@TYPE': O
        - '@IDX': '2'
          '@LOC': /oracle/19.0.0
          '@NAME': OraDB19Home1
          '@TYPE': O
      VERSION_INFO:
        MINIMUM_VER: 2.1.0.6.0
        SAVED_WITH: 13.9.4.0.0
```

Create a dictionary of LOC and NAME

```yaml
  loc_name: "{{ inv_yml.INVENTORY.HOME_LIST.HOME|
                items2dict(key_name='@LOC',
                           value_name='@NAME') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  loc_name:
    /oracle/19.0.0: OraDB19Home1
    /oracle/agent/agent13.4: OraHome1
```

Then, searching is trivial

```yaml
  loc: '/oracle/19.0.0'
  name_of_loc: "{{ loc_name[loc] }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  name_of_loc: OraDB19Home1
```

, or in the loop

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "The name of LOC {{ item }} is {{ loc_name[item] }}"
      loop:
        - '/oracle/19.0.0'
        - '/oracle/agent/agent13.4'
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: The name of LOC /oracle/19.0.0 is OraDB19Home1
  msg: The name of LOC /oracle/agent/agent13.4 is OraHome1
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    inv_xml: "{{ lookup('file', 'inventory.xml') }}"
    inv_yml: "{{ inv_xml|ansible.utils.from_xml }}"
    loc_name: "{{ inv_yml.INVENTORY.HOME_LIST.HOME|
                  items2dict(key_name='@LOC',
                             value_name='@NAME') }}"
    loc: '/oracle/19.0.0'
    name_of_loc: "{{ loc_name[loc] }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: inv_xml
    - debug:
        var: inv_yml
    - debug:
        var: loc_name
    - debug:
        var: name_of_loc

    - debug:
        msg: "The name of LOC {{ item }} is {{ loc_name[item] }}"
      loop:
        - '/oracle/19.0.0'
        - '/oracle/agent/agent13.4'
```

Example of the project

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── inventory.xml
└── pb.yml

0 directories, 4 files
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
collections_path = $HOME/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
inventory = $PWD/hosts
roles_path = $PWD/roles
remote_tmp = ~/.ansible/tmp
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml
```

```ini
shell> cat hosts 
localhost
```

---

Q: ***"Give an alternative to *ansible.utils*"***

A: Install [*jc*](https://kellyjonbrazil.github.io/jc/docs/) and use it in the pipe. The declaration below expands to the same YAML as before

```yaml
  inv_yml: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'cat inventory.xml | jc --xml') }}"
```

---

Q: ***"Using possible regex?"***

A: Select the line first

```yaml
  inv_xml: "{{ lookup('file', 'inventory.xml') }}"

  loc: '/oracle/19.0.0'
  home_loc_regex: '^\s*<HOME .*? LOC="{{ loc }}" .*$'
  home: "{{ inv_xml.splitlines()|
            select('regex', home_loc_regex)|
            first|
            trim }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  home: <HOME NAME="OraDB19Home1" LOC="/oracle/19.0.0" TYPE="O" IDX="2"/>
```

Parse the attributes

```yaml
  home_dict: "{{ dict(home[6:-2]|
                      replace('\"', '')|
                      split(' ')|
                      map('split', '=')) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  home_dict:
    IDX: '2'
    LOC: /oracle/19.0.0
    NAME: OraDB19Home1
    TYPE: O
```

---

Q: ***"No filter named 'split'"***

A: The filter [*split*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#manipulating-strings) is available since 2.11. For the lower versions, only the '*.split*' method is available. In this case, use Jinja and create the YAML structure. The declarations below give the same dictionary *home_dict* as before

```yaml
  home_dict_str: |
    {% for i in home[6:-2].split(' ') %}
    {% set arr = i.split('=') %}
    {{ arr.0 }}: {{ arr.1 }}
    {% endfor %}
  home_dict: "{{ home_dict_str|from_yaml }}"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was looking at these to improvise, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72022134/how-can-i-convert-key-value-file-into-ansible-facts and the following that you answered in another thread, lost the link for that.    - set_fact:
        MQSFILEPARSED: "{{ lookup('file', FILE).splitlines()|
                           select('match', '^(.*) LOC=(.*)$')|
                           map('regex_replace', my_regex, my_replace)|
                           list }}"

Comment: Getting ansible.utils is proving to be challenging. Appreciate if you can give an alternative using possible regex? Thanks once again.

Comment: Use *jc* instead. I added an example. What's challenging on *ansible.utils*?

Comment: I added the 'regex' option.

Comment: Thank you so much once again! Our server admins aren't willing to add those utils. Thats where I develop the playbooks. These will eventually go on the Tower. And the Tower env doesnt have these utils installed. When I checked with the tower admin he said, I'll have to have a custom exec env. Wasnt sure how much of it I wanted to dabble with limited time etc. Appreciate your help always. I am racking up beers for you here in Houston :)

Comment: Good to know :) Take a look if [Community.General](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general) is available to you. This is where the new stuff is added and updated. For example, you can use [*jc*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/jc_filter.html#community-general-jc-filter-convert-output-of-many-shell-commands-and-file-types-to-json) also as a filter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251736/discussion-between-calsaint-and-vladimir-botka).

Answer (score 1):

This is almost trivial to do with awk:

Formatted as a script file:

```
/<HOME NAME=.*TYPE=.*IDX=/ {
    if ($3 == "LOC=\"/oracle/19.0.0\"") {
        split($2, a, /"/);
        print a[2];
        exit;
    }
}'
```

Command line:

```bash
cat your_input_file | awk '/<HOME NAME=.*TYPE=.*IDX=/{ if ($3 == "LOC=\"/oracle/19.0.0\"") { split($2, a, /"/); print a[2]; exit }  }'
```

You can probably convert this relatively easily to something similar in python.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I currently use something similar in an existing shell script which I am trying to write as an ansible playbook. So was looking for something ansible solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v loc='LOC="/oracle/19.0.0"' '
    index($0,loc){
        print gensub(/^.*NAME="([^"]*)".*$/,"\\1",1)
    }
' inputfile
```

or

```
awk -F'=|"' -v loc='LOC="/oracle/19.0.0"' 'index($0,loc){print $3}' inputfile
awk -F'=|"' -v loc="/oracle/19.0.0" '/ LOC="[^"]*" / && $6 == loc {print $3}' inputfile
```

Output

```
OraDB19Home1
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the use case looks like a

**Similar Q&A**

- [Ansible: How to pull a specific string out of the contents of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75099369/6771046)

It is assumed that the unfavorable data structure within your configuration example file stays as it is provided and you are looking for a `grep` approach in Ansible.

```yaml
- name: Gather home directory
  shell:
    cmd: "grep '{{ VERSION }}' inventory.xml | cut -d '=' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | tr -d '"'"
  register: home_dir
```

---

**How to proceed further?**

If such lookup's are necessary frequently or on a greater scale, one might take advantage from implementing a specific solution.

If the installation of [`ansible.utils.collection`](https://galaxy.ansible.com/ansible/utils) and [Python library `xmltodict`](https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/) is possible or already available, you should definitely [go with the recommended solution from Vladimir Botka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75382671/6771046) of [`from_xml` filter – Convert given XML string to native python dictionary](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/ansible/utils/from_xml_filter.html) by converting XML to YAML before further processing.

Otherwise you could give a try for

**Custom Module Examples**

- Bash: [File search ... with Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74614509/6771046)
- Bash: [How to check if a file is of type human-readable in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75150122/6771046)
- Python: [How to search for a string in a Remote File using Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75250253/6771046)

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the help. Was trying to steer clear of cmd/shell and do it natively in ansbile.