# Finding XPATH for specific attribute on Ansible XML module

Tags: xml, xpath, ansible

I am having a super hard time understanding how to gather a specific attribute as a variable from a sample piece of XML.

```xml
<response status="success">
    <result>
        <interface name="ethernet1-1" id="258" allocated="40" total="150">
            <entry name="10.10.10.1">
                <ip>10.10.10.1</ip>
                <mac>aa:aa:bb:bb:cc:cc</mac>
            </entry>
            <entry name="10.10.10.2">
                <ip>10.10.10.2</ip>
                <mac>11:11:22:22:33:33</mac>
            </entry>
            ...
```

The goal being to grab '40' or '150' as its own object. I have tried various sample XPATHs on several pages, but I am not understanding how it works apparently.

I have the module currently set to:

```yaml
- name: Gather allocated number of addresses for LAN interface...
  community.general.xml:
    xmlstring: "{{ ethernet1-1_output_fixed }}"
    xpath: "/x:response/x:result/x:interface[@name='ethernet1-1']"
    content: attribute
  register: allocated_ethernet1-1
```

But the command keeps kicking back an undefined namespace error:

```
TASK [Gather allocated number of addresses for LAN interface...] 
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. 
The error was: lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Undefined namespace prefix
```

Comment: Your XML sample has no XML namespaces. Though XPath expression is using "x" as a namespace prefix. Just remove it from the XPath expression.

Comment: So you are saying if I use:

'/response/result/interface[@name='ethernet1-1']' 

Should be correct?

Comment: You can try `/response/result/interface[@name='ethernet1-1']@total`

Comment: Nope. No dice. 

Syntax error in xpath expression: /response/result/interface[@name='ethernet1-1']@total (Invalid expression)

Comment: Fat fingers. Please try the following: `/response/result/interface[@name="ethernet1-1"]/@total`

Comment: "Xpath /response/result/interface[@name='ethernet1-1']/@total does not reference a node!"

Seems like it cant find that path either.

Answer (score 1):

Please take note that in the following examples the XML content/input was moved into a file **`eth.xml`** for simplification. Please take also note about [Creating valid variable names](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names) because of

```yaml
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! =>
  msg: 'Invalid variable name in ''register'' specified: ''allocated_ethernet1-1'''
```

> ***How to gather a specific attribute as a variable from a sample piece of XML?***

Overall, make use of the [`debug` module – Print statements during execution](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html) in order to get familiar the [Common Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html) and resulting data structures.

---

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Gather allocated number of addresses for LAN interface...
    community.general.xml:
      path: eth.xml
      xpath: '/response/result/interface[@name="ethernet1-1"]'
      content: attribute
    register: result

  - debug:
      var: result.matches
```

will return a list of `interface` nodes where the `name` value is equal the given search value (`interface[@name="<...>"]`), here a list with one element only and result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] **********
ok: [localhost] =>
  result.matches:
  - interface:
      allocated: '40'
      id: '258'
      name: ethernet1-1
      total: '150'
```

> ***The goal being to grab '40' or '150' as its own object.***

Gathering the value of `allocated` or `total` of `interfaces` becomes trivial now.

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ (result.matches | first).interface }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ (result.matches | first).interface.allocated }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ (result.matches | first).interface.total }}"
```

outputs

```yaml
TASK [debug] ********
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
    allocated: '40'
    id: '258'
    name: ethernet1-1
    total: '150'

TASK [debug] ********
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: '40'

TASK [debug] ********
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: '150'
```

---

A different approach could be [Using filters to manipulate data](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html) like shown in an other minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    XML: "{{ lookup('file', 'eth.xml') }}"
    YML: "{{ XML | ansible.utils.from_xml }}"

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ YML.response.result }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ YML.response.result.interface['@total'] }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *******************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
    interface:
      '@allocated': '40'
      '@id': '258'
      '@name': ethernet1-1
      '@total': '150'
      entry:
      - '@name': 10.10.10.1
        ip: 10.10.10.1
        mac: aa:aa:bb:bb:cc:cc
      - '@name': 10.10.10.2
        ip: 10.10.10.2
        mac: '11:11:22:22:33:33'

TASK [debug] *******************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: '150'
```

**Similar Q&A and Documentation**

- [`from_xml` filter – Convert given XML string to native Python dictionary](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/from_xml_filter.html)
- [Ansilbe XML searching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75529186/6771046)

Comment: This is what I needed. Thank you. Only question I have is how you managed to get your output to look that clean. Mine is usually a block of text that is hard to read without putting through another program.

Comment: That's just an [Callback Plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html) called [`yaml`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/index_callback.html). See in example [How to format Ansible logs in a human readable way?](https://serverfault.com/a/1013778/448950) and [`yaml` callback – YAML-ized Ansible screen output](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/yaml_callback.html#ansible-collections-community-general-yaml-callback). There are already plenty of Q&A regarding configuring it here on stackoverflow, as well serverfault.

Comment: Yep, all I needed was the pointer in the right direction. I will be using that more often. Super appreciate the help, will test later today.

Comment: Worked perfectly. The callbacks formatted in YAML are also super helpful. This is going to make troubleshooting a ton faster.

Answer (score 0):

U880D's idea appears to have worked. Specifically the:

"{{ (result.matches | first).interface.subitem }}"

Answer (score -1):

Here is what works for me.

[XPath Fiddle](https://witty-dune-0fb497610.3.azurestaticapps.net/?code=%2Fresponse%2Fresult%2Finterface%5B%40name%3D%22ethernet1-1%22%5D%2F%40total&input=%3Cresponse%20status%3D%22success%22%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cresult%3E%0D%0A%09%09%3Cinterface%20name%3D%22ethernet1-1%22%20id%3D%22258%22%20allocated%3D%2240%22%20total%3D%22150%22%3E%0D%0A%09%09%09%3Centry%20name%3D%2210.10.10.1%22%3E%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%3Cip%3E10.10.10.1%3C%2Fip%3E%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%3Cmac%3Eaa%3Aaa%3Abb%3Abb%3Acc%3Acc%3C%2Fmac%3E%0D%0A%09%09%09%3C%2Fentry%3E%0D%0A%09%09%09%3Centry%20name%3D%2210.10.10.2%22%3E%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%3Cip%3E10.10.10.2%3C%2Fip%3E%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%3Cmac%3E11%3A11%3A22%3A22%3A33%3A33%3C%2Fmac%3E%0D%0A%09%09%09%3C%2Fentry%3E%0D%0A%09%09%3C%2Finterface%3E%0D%0A%09%3C%2Fresult%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fresponse%3E&code-type=XPath&input-type=XML)

**Input XML**

```
<response status="success">
    <result>
        <interface name="ethernet1-1" id="258" allocated="40" total="150">
            <entry name="10.10.10.1">
                <ip>10.10.10.1</ip>
                <mac>aa:aa:bb:bb:cc:cc</mac>
            </entry>
            <entry name="10.10.10.2">
                <ip>10.10.10.2</ip>
                <mac>11:11:22:22:33:33</mac>
            </entry>
        </interface>
    </result>
</response>
```

**XPath**

```
/response/result/interface[@name="ethernet1-1"]/@total
```

**Output**

```
150
```

Comment: While I see it does work in the XML tool you linked, it is not working in the Ansible module. 

I continue to get a:

"Xpath /response/result/interface[@name='ethernet1-1]/@allocated does not reference a node!"

Comment: The XPath in question returns textual value of 150. Not an element or attribute!

Comment: I changed my content tag from 'attribute' to 'text' with no effect. That being said, isn't what I am querying for an attribute?